# Joomla 3 - How to find if logged in user is registered?

Tags: joomla

I have the following code

`<?php if ($user->id >= 1): // logged in ?>`

This checks to see if the user is logged in but not which group the user belongs to. I'm trying to show content only for registered users.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

//Get the logged user

```
$user = JFactory::getUser($user->id >= 1);
```

//Set the group id to check against

```
$group_id = 9;
```

//see if the user is in bo

```
if( in_array($group_id, $user->groups ) ){ 
echo "User is in group"
}else{
 echo "user not in group";
}
```

//Side note: You can also get user groups with the following method

```
$user->getAuthorisedGroups();
```